# What is purpose of android:id in PreferenceCategory?

Tags: android

I don't know why Google need design a `android:id` for PreferenceCategory in Code B.

It seems that I find the control only based by `android:key` just like Code A.

What  is purpose of `android:id` in PreferenceCategory ? Can I always remove `android:id="@+id/chAutoRestore"`  ?

**Code A**

```
 val chAutoRestore = preferenceManager.findPreference(getString(R.string.IsAutoRestore)) as CheckBoxPreference
```

**Code B**

```
  <PreferenceCategory android:title="Auto Restore">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:id="@+id/chAutoRestore"          //I think that it's  supernumerary  
            android:key="@string/IsAutoRestore"
            android:summary="Auto restore every 15"
            android:title="Auto Restore" />

    </PreferenceCategory>
```

Comment: seems that `android:id` is not used by any `PreferenceCategory` code at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android:id
```

this attribute is not used in PreferenceCategory  or CheckBoxPreference.

always use

```
android:key
```

above attribute instead of id for accessing that view.